# Convert DataFrame to a Matrix and access a cell

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this DF

```
Customer_ID | product_No | Rating
7           | 1223       | 2.0
9           | 1254       | 1.0
8           | 1223       | 5.0
3           | 1265       | 3.0
```

I want to convert it into a matrix and fill empty values with 0 like this:

```
Customer_ID\product_No   | 1223 | 1254 | 1265
7                        | 2.0  |  0.0 | 0.0
9                        | 0.0  |  1.0 | 0.0
8                        | 5.0  |  5.0 | 0.0
3                        | 0.0  |  0.0 | 3.0
```

I wrote this code to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

ratings = pd.read_csv("ratings.csv",names['Customer_ID','product_No','Rating'])


matrix= ratings.groupby(['Customer_ID','product_No']).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)

print (matrix)
```

Now when I want to access an item but I could not. I tried this

```
matrix.loc[7][1223]
```

but I get 0 !!

Can you help me please
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) for the columns.

```
>>> matrix.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Rating'], [1223, 1254, 1265]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2]],
           names=[None, u'product_No'])
```

You could instead do:

```
matrix.loc[7]['Rating'][1223]
```

Or if you wanted to use just index numbers you could do:

```
matrix.iloc[1][0]
```

Comment: Thank you, bernie.
Is there a way to use index numbers (as in 2d arrays) instead of the real values?
For example, [0][0] will give the value of first left cell and so on

Comment: Sure, you could also do: `matrix.iloc[1][0]`. I will amend the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much